# apt file and sql repository error on app deployment in Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, heroku-toolbelt

Newbie here. I am trying to deploy an app in Heroku. All the code and files are in github.

In the review apps, the app is working just fine, but when it is in production, I don't understand why it is not working anymore.

Here is the Build log:

-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git
-----> R (shiny) app detected
-----> Installing R
Version 4.2.1 will be installed on heroku-22 stack.
-----> Downloading buildpack archives from AWS S3
Downloading https://heroku-buildpack-r.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/heroku-buildpack-r-22-4.2.1-deploy.tar.gz
Downloading https://heroku-buildpack-r.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/heroku-buildpack-r-22-4.2.1-shiny.tar.gz
Setting up build environment
Downloading https://heroku-buildpack-r.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/heroku-buildpack-r-22-4.2.1-chroot.tar.gz
-----> Configuring build environment...

## WARNING: Use of the Aptfile file is NOT recommended and will be deprecated in future.

```
   For greater control and flexibility consider using the Heroku
   container stack together with the heroku-docker-r implementation.
   See https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-docker-r for more information.
   W: No sandbox user '_apt' on the system, can not drop privileges
   W: GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
   E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease' is not signed.
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile R (shiny) app.
!     Push failed

Anyone can help me on this? I really can't find anywhere the solution. I am newbie in deployment of Apps.

I have tried generating new keys and importing GPG but it didn't work.